# Does sencha touch supports windows8

Tags: windows, sencha-touch, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing `windows8` application for that I am using `sencha touch` and `cordova`. I am able to add the platform using `cordova platfrom add windows` 
But when I am importing the same windows project in `visual studio running on my windows8.0 maching` it's saying you need windows 8.1. I am confused if `sencha touch` supported `windows8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha does support Windows 8. But the issue that you are experiencing relates more to Visual Studio and Cordova.

I'd suggest to upgrade to Windows 8.1 as it provides better API and supports the latest SDKs. But if you still want to develop for Windows 8 make sure you installed Windows 8 (not Windows 8.1) SDK. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx

Comment: yes you are right when i am running the sencha project individually its working but the moment i am adding it to cordova project its crashing..any idea why its crashing.clue :1 when i am adding the secha microloader file its crashing if i am removing that its not crashing..

Comment: I'd try to debug your application in Visual Studio. Also, there are some differences between JavaScript and WinJS. Especially in terms of security. Very often you have to wrap your code in execUnsafeLocalFunction: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767331.aspx